# Come tradurre: Announcement emails?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

Questa comunità si sta rivelando utilissima :)

Secondo voi come posso tradurre in italiano **Announcements emails**?

Si tratta di email che vengono inviate a tutti i partecipanti di un evento per avvisarli di cambiamenti dell'ultimo minuto, per annunci vari o informazioni generali.

**Email di annunci** non mi suona.

Aggiungere un aggettivo alla parola email non mi convince.

Lascio **Annunci** dando per scontato che sono via email?

Oppure **Annunci via email**?

Un esempio da tradurre è la seguente frase:

Il partecipante preferisce non ricevere *announcement emails*.

Grazie mille!

Comment: “Comunicazioni”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La prima forma che mi viene in mente sarebbe ***Email di notifica***, oppure ***notifiche via email***.

Il termine è molto usato in relazione a siti web e applicazioni in generale, pensa alle notifiche di Whatsapp, Facebook etc.

Altre possibilità potrebbero essere ***avvisi via email*** oppure ***comunicazioni*** ***via email***, sicuramente trovo stridente l'espressione ***email di annunci***.

Comment: Grazie. Le notifiche le vedrei forse più legate al contesto app. Ti arriva la notifica che ti è arrivato un messaggio. In questo caso sono degli annunci riguardanti l'evento. Che dici metto Avvisi via email?

Comment: Io sviluppo applicazioni web e nella mia esperienza utilizzo maggiormente "email di notifica" o semplicemente "notifiche". Nel tuo caso specifico penso tuttavia che possa andare bene "Avvisi via email"

Answer (score 3):

`Comunicazioni di servizio` è un'altra possibilità; secondo me si presta molto bene a rappresentare il tipo di annunci che descrivi. Se è importante specificare che si tratta di comunicazioni via email potresti semplicemente dire `Comunicazioni di servizio via email` o `Email di servizio`.

A prescindere, secondo me ti conviene eliminare la parola `annunci` perché in italiano richiama più che altro il concetto di annunci sul giornale, annunci di compravendita usato e cose del genere.

Comment: Grazie della risposta. Si in effetti annunci la usavo come traduzione sbagliata di announcements. Molto meglio avvisi.